# How to increment a record with +1 each time MySql

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

Hello I have a table that has the movieName, releasedMonth, cost and revenue for movies. I am trying to write a query that will change/update the name of any movie LIKE 'Cars' to Zip Cars.

In my table I have the movie Cars and Cars 2, I need to have 1 query that will change Cars to Zip Cars and Cars 2 to Zip Cars 2. Below is my table and the query I've tried but haven't gotten to work

Note I thought you would need to use AUTO_INCREMENT but I cannot get it working. Any help is greatly appreciated thank you.

```
CREATE TABLE movies_200249154(
  movieName VARCHAR(30),
  releaseDate DATE,
  costInMillions INT,
  revenueInMillions INT
);


UPDATE movies_200249154
SET moviename ='Zip-Cars'
WHERE moviename LIKE '%Cars%';
```

Answer (score 0):

REPLACE is your friend.

Use:

```
UPDATE movies_200249154
SET moviename =
  REPLACE(moviename, 'Cars', 'Zap-Cars') WHERE moviename LIKE '%Cars%';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just looking to use the Replace function in MySql:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

```
UPDATE movies_200249154 SET moviename = REPLACE(moviename, "Cars", "Zip Cars") WHERE moviename like '%Cars%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Just concat Zip- and the original value.

```
update movies_200249154
set moviename = concat('Zip-', moviename)
where moviename like 'Cars%'
```